# Conocer ultimo offset leído Kafka - Spark Streaming

Tags: java, kafka, spark

Buen día,
Me encuentro aprendiendo Spark y Kafka, tengo una aplicación streaming usando el **API para java** de spark. Mi problema radica en ¿cómo poder conocer cual fue el último offset leído? Por ejemplo mi aplicación lee constantemente de kafka, de pronto se cae y en el topic kafka llegan mensajes. Quiero hacer que cuando se levante mi aplicación Spark, continúe leyendo apartir del offset que se leyó antes de la caída.
Con kafkaUtils si coloco:

> auto.offset.reset=earliest

Me lee todo el topic, si lo cambio a **latest** me lee los records que llegan una vez se inicia la aplicación, por lo que no cumple con lo que quiero, ya que tendría perdida de datos de kafka.
Agregue un **checkPoint**, entiendo que esto funciona cuando no se termino de leer un DStream, si se cae  puede continuar con un trabajo que se vio interrumpido.

Código de configuración:

Spark config:

```
return new SparkConf().setMaster(sparkDriverUtils.getSparkMaster())
                .setAppName(sparkDriverUtils.getSparkAppName() == null ? "name-not-set"
                        : sparkDriverUtils.getSparkAppName())
                .set("spark.default.parallelism", "2")
                
                .set("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts", "1")
                .set("spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval", "2h")
                            
                .set(DriverConstants.SPARK_MAX_CORES, sparkDriverUtils.getSparkMaxCores())
                .set(DriverConstants.SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY, sparkDriverUtils.getSparkExecutorMemory());
```

Fragmento para Kafka:
Parametros Kafka :

```
kafkaParams.put(DriverConstants.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, getBootstrapServers());// 1 or more brokers
        kafkaParams.put(DriverConstants.KEY_DESERIALIZER, StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put(DriverConstants.VALUE_DESERIALIZER, StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put(DriverConstants.KAFKA_GROUP_ID, getGroupId());
        kafkaParams.put(DriverConstants.KAFKA_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET, getAutoOffsetReset()); //earliest  o latest
    kafkaParams.put(DriverConstants.KAFKA_ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT, getEnableAutoCommit()); //false



    JavaStreamingContext jssc = sparkConfigurationBuilder
            .buildJSC(sparkConfigurationBuilder.buildSparkConfiguration());
            
    jssc.checkpoint("C:\\tmp\\poc\\checkPoint");
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = sparkDriverUtils.getKafkaProperties();        
    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(sparkDriverUtils.getTopics().trim().split(","));// 1 o more topics        


JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución a mi problema, para la configuración de Spark agregué [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) :

```
return new SparkConf().set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true").set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown" , "true")...;
```

Parametros para kafka:

```
auto.offset.reset=latest
enable.auto.commit=false
```

Para implementar el checkPoint cambié la forma de  crear SparkStreaming:

```
private static JavaStreamingContext createContext(String checkpointDirectory ) {


    System.out.println("Creating new context");
   
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount");

    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(5));
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory);

    //Codigo con acciones, transformaciones para RDD...

    return ssc;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String checkpointDirectory = "/tmp/directory/checkpoint";
    Function0<JavaStreamingContext> createContextFunc =
        () -> createContext(checkpointDirectory);

    JavaStreamingContext ssc =
      JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, createContextFunc);
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
  }
}
```